# Font family changes for safari browser

Tags: css, safari

`font-famil` is same for all browser except safari

**CSS** for applying `font-family` throughout the application body

```
body {
   height: 100%;
   font-size: .80em;
   font-family : "PT Sans","Century Gothic",Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   color: Black;
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 1):

For windows  google font PT Sans is not supported for safari browser.
[See here in the git hub](https://github.com/vladpopa33/googlefontdirectory/issues/330)

Answer (score 0):

Use [google PT Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/PT+Sans?selection.family=PT%20Sans) font

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
```

OR you may download PT Sans webkit font from [this](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/pt-sans?q%5Bterm%5D=pt%20sans&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y) website and include individually in you website